# DHCP PowerShell cmdlets from PC

Tags: powershell, windows-10, dhcp, powershell-5.0

Can I use DHCP PowerShell cmdlets from a Windows 10 desktop? I have searched online a lot but only come up with results about using the cmdlets from the server. If my PC is on the DHCP server I would think there is a way to use the cmdlets from my PC. I am looking to get information about the IP addresses that are currently in use or available, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You have to install [RSAT for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) and then make sure the DHCP tools part of RSAT is enabled.

Note that you will have to specify the DHCP server in the `-ComputerName` parameter of each call, or create a CIM session and use that.